# Indy IdTCPServer Issues

Tags: server, client, delphi-7, indy

I have recently installed indy 10.0.52 , but every time am trying to write codes inside the OnExecute event for IdTCPServer , Delphi showing Error : **Unknown identifier  TIdContext** , & this also happened with TByte Type ..
I have tried to re-install the packages but in-vain ..

Delphi 7 Enterprise  , Win7

Comment: Please show the code around the line where the error occurs.

Comment: 10.0.52 is an extremely old version of Indy. Why are you using that version? The current version is 10.6.2. As for the errors, make sure you have the `IdContext` unit in your `uses` clause. And Delphi 7 does not have the `TBytes` type. Do you mean `TIdBytes` instead? That is in the `IdGlobal` unit.

Comment: where to download this version @RemyLebeau . Indy site is not working in my area.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have tried what you have mentioned (make sure you have the IdContext unit in your uses) and it works with the current version of indy... but am looking forward to get the latest ver of it ..

Comment: @Issam the latest source code is at https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy, also see https://www.indyproject.org/2021/02/10/links-to-old-indy-website-pages-are-currently-broken/